# Semi-custom TOC numbering

Tags: table-of-contents

I apologize if this has been asked before, but none of the other TOC questions seemed to precisely match what I am looking for.

I would like to, with as minimal as possible changes to the standard usage of the TOC package, create a TOC that alters just one chapter (the introduction).

For example with the following MWE of my current set up:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preamble}

\section{Motivation}
\section{Outline}

\chapter{Blah}
\section{Blah}
\section{Blah}

\chapter{Blah}
\section{Blah}
\section{Blah}
\end{document}
```

I get this output

```
1 Preamble
 1.1 Motivation
 1.2 Outline
2 Blah
 2.1 Blah
 2.2 Blah
3 Blah
 3.1 Blah
 3.2 Blah
```

Where what I would like is

```
  Preamble
     Motivation
     Outline
1 Blah
 1.1 Blah
 1.2 Blah
2 Blah
 2.1 Blah
 2.2 Blah
```

And it still be hyperlinked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
{\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\chapter*{Preamble}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\hspace*{1.3em}Preamble}}

\section{Motivation}
\section{Outline}
}

\chapter{Blah}
\section{Blah}
\section{Blah}

\chapter{Blah}
\section{Blah}
\section{Blah}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Bernard, thanks for your help! Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Namely, I realized that I forgot to mention that I am using \usepackage{hyperref} which seems to screw the whole affair up. I've editied accordingly. Sorry!

Comment: There must be something else. Adding  hyperref still works here with my code. Could you post a minimal non-working example?

Comment: It was no problem! I just made a slight mistake when typing in what you had written. Thanks!